# How do I negate the $.is function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery has a function called 'is' that checks for a given property, for example:

```
$('#article').is(':visible')
```

This will check if div#article is visible.

However I can't find the is-not function. I'd like to write:

```
$('#article').is-not(':visible')
```

What is it?

I checked the docs and found `.not` but I realized that `.not` does something completely different than the "`.is-not`" function that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** To negate any expression, apply [the logical *not* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), `!`:

```
!$('#article').is(':visible')
```

**2.** Or you could use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector...

```
$('#article').is(":not(:visible)")
```

**3.** Options 1 & 2 are general solutions which will work to negate any selector provided to `is()`. In this *particular* case, you can test if an element is *not* [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) by testing if it *is* [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)...

```
$('#article').is(":hidden")
```

---

Samples:

```js
var $a = $("#article");
console.log("logical not: %s", !$a.is(":visible"));
console.log("not selector: %s",$a.is(":not(:visible)"));
console.log("hidden selector: %s", $a.is(":hidden"));
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<div id="article" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Could also use `$('#article').is(':hidden')`.

Comment: the `.is()` method returns boolean true or false, so to find the opposite, just use the `!` operator as @canon said